# MS Bot framework v4 - cannot add QnA maker to bot - hostname encrypted value is not a valid format

Tags: node.js, botframework, azure-bot-service, azure-qna-maker

**Current situation:** I currently have a working web app bot with LUIS integration (NODE.js). I want to add a QnA maker to the bot. I have created a QnA maker via the Azure bot service and created a knowledge base for it to use.

**Issue:** When adding the qna maker details to the bot and running with nodemon ./index.js, I get the error "Error: The encrypted value is not a valid format". I've tested and this error is thrown when it tries to read the hostname value during

> ```
> botConfig = BotConfiguration.loadSync(BOT_FILE, process.env.botFileSecret);
> ```

When pasting the hostname into the browser Azure shows me a "Your App Service app is up and running" page, indicating the hostname is fine.

**Questions:**

1. How do I debug this further? Could it be something to do with how the QnA maker is set up?
2. Both the QnA maker and Knoledge base is published - is there something I have to add manually to the config of the bot via the Azure portal to get it to recognise the QnA maker?

A lot of the documentation is based on v3 of the bot framework and have no idea if it's still applicable.

QnA snippet in Bot file (some values omitted, not sure how sensitive they are):

```
{
  "type": "qna",
  "name": "pathqna",
  "KbId": "OMITTED",
  "subscriptionId": "OMITTED",
  "endpointKey": "OMITTED",
  "hostname": "https://pathqna.azurewebsites.net",
  "id": "7"
}
```

Documentation I've looked at:

1. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-gb/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-tutorial-dispatch?view=azure-bot-service-4.0&tabs=javascript
2. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/qnamaker/tutorials/create-qna-bot
3. https://github.com/Microsoft/botbuilder-tools/blob/master/packages/MSBot/docs/sample-bot-file.json
4. https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/QnAMaker/how-to/troubleshooting-runtime#how-to-get-latest-qnamaker-runtime-updates

Full bot file with the empty padlock value (all OMITTED values have real keys and name has been changed to Test):

```
{
  "name": “Test”,
  "padlock": "",
  "version": "2.0",
  "services": [
    {
      "tenantId": "OMITTED",
      "subscriptionId": "OMITTED",
      "resourceGroup": OMITTED,
      "serviceName": OMITTED,
      "type": "abs",
      "name": OMITTED,
      "id": "1"
    },
    {
      "connectionString": "OMITTED",
      "tenantId": "OMITTED",
      "subscriptionId": "OMITTED",
      "resourceGroup": OMITTED,
      "serviceName": "patha048",
      "type": "blob",
      "id": "2"
    },
    {
    “appId": "OMITTED",
      "appPassword": “OMITTED”,
      "endpoint": "http://localhost:3978/api/messages",
      "type": "endpoint",
      "name": "development",
      "id": "3"
    },
    {
      "appId": "OMITTED",
      "appPassword": “OMITTED”,
      "endpoint": "https://path-a048.azurewebsites.net/api/messages",
      "type": "endpoint",
      "name": "production",
      "id": "4"
    },
    {
      "instrumentationKey": “OMITTED”,
      "applicationId": “OMITTED”,
      "apiKeys": {},
      "tenantId": "OMITTED",
      "subscriptionId": "OMITTED",
      "resourceGroup": OMITTED,
      "serviceName": "Patht6r6m4",
      "type": "appInsights",
      "id": "5"
    },
    {
      "appId": “OMITTED”,
      "authoringKey": “OMITTED”,
      "version": "0.1",
      "region": "westus",
      "type": "luis",
      "name": "BasicBotLuisApplication",
      "id": "6"
    },
    {
      "type": "qna",
      "name": "pathqna",
      "id": "7",
      "kbId": “OMITTED”,
      "subscriptionKey": "OMITTED",
      "endpointKey": “OMITTED”,
      "hostname": "https://pathqna.azurewebsites.net"
    }
  ]
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the solution - Use msbot cli to add the QnA maker instead of adding manually as the file is encrypted and loses it's decryption if you don't use the msbot/emulator *shrug*

I removed the qna snippet and ran this command (have added the generic values to preserve the real values):

```
msbot connect qna --secret <botFileSecret> --name pathqna --kbId <KB-ID> --subscriptionKey <SUB_KEY> --endpointKey <ENDPOINT_KEY> --hostname "https://pathqna.azurewebsites.net" --bot Path.bot
```

This preserved the padlock value and added it successfully.

Comment: One additional comment: If you want to edit the .bot file manually, here is the documentation for decrypting and afterwards re-encrypting your .bot file: https://learn.microsoft.com/de-de/azure/bot-service/bot-builder-deploy-az-cli?view=azure-bot-service-4.0

Answer (score 0):

Although the information you have provided is not enough to provide a solution, you may please check on the following steps.

**"Error: The encrypted value is not a valid format"**
*Please check your bot secret keys once again.

Then, in your bot file, try removing the padlock value.

```
"padlock": ""
```

Also, I assume in your actual code, you have replaced '**OMITTED**' with the real time keys that you have obtained from QnAMaker portal.*

Provide a screenshot of the error if possible.

Comment: If I remove the padlock value I'm able to register the qna service, however the app no longer works due to the error " [onTurnError]: Error: Response 401: The key used is invalid, malformed, empty, or doesn't match the region."

I've removed the qna snippet in the bot file and removed the padlock value, and it gives the same error.

What is the padlock value? Can I regenerate it? I can't find any documentation on it.

Comment: Can u share the .bot file ?

Comment: I've updated the original post to include the full bot file (too long to add as a comment)